# react-native TouchableHighlight disable onPress color flickering

Tags: react-native, flicker, touchablehighlight, onpress

I want to disable the "color blink" or "color flickering" effect that blackens the image when TouchableHighlight gets pressed.

Here is the screen render:

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={this._onPressButton}>
                  <Image
                  source={require('../../img/fish.png')}
                  style={[styles.iconSize, styles.iconMarginRight]}/>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

How do i accomplish that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [`TouchableWithoutFeedback`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback.html) or set `activeOpacity` to 1.0.

Comment: save my day, best ever answer

Answer (score 2):

If you must use [TouchableHighlight](https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchablehighlight)

You can set the [underlayColor](https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchablehighlight#underlaycolor) property of [TouchableHighlight Component](https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchablehighlight)

The default for this property is black.